# Is there an simple but good To Do Manager app for the Mac?

Tags: mac

Every morning I think about what I am going to do today. So I take a paper and start to write things like:

[ ] Call Mr. XYZ

[ ] Answer Support E-Mails

[ ] Reduce website header height by 20 px

[ ] Create new navigation bar icons

And every time I'm done with something, I paint a checkmark in this square. On paper. It would be fun to have something like this as an application. But I don't want a heavy project management tool or integration with email. It should be like download, install, use  without fat configuration and steep learning curve. usually I don't schedule my to do's, I just write down every day what I want to accomplish today.

For my experience it doesn't make sense to plan what to do next week, because next week everything looks totally different.

Would be cool if such a simple utility exists. At the moment I try just using textEdit and deleting rows which are done. With a nice interface, this would be much more fun.

Comment: What about RememberTheMilk or Google Tasks / Google Calendar? (All of them are easy to use but can be used professionally, you can sync them with your phone, other PCs, whatever.) Or I use Dropbox+Notepad sometimes for scratch notes. :)

Comment: Here's a fairly comprehensive list of [ToDo List Software](http://hellofocus.com/todo-list-software).  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Taskpaper](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/taskpaper)

Answer (score 3):

I use [TaskWarrior](http://taskwarrior.org).

Answer (score 2):

you can use iCal for this sort of thing.  Another nice tool is the Tasks tool that comes with gmail.  This requires an account, but the benefit is that your list will be available away from your home computer.

Answer (score 2):

I use [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnifocus/) (iGTD is a free alternative, although it's no longer developed; the dev left to work on Things, another nice alternative) for keeping my tasks organized. It's a great way to implement David Allen's "Getting Things Done" (GTD) technique, which I've also found really helpful.

OmniFocus has an iPhone version; Things is on iPhone and iPad as well.

I'd include URLs to iGTD and Things (Google for iGTD, it'll also have a link to Things) but I'm a n00b.

Answer (score 2):

http://culturedcode.com/things/

Comment: really good one!

Answer (score 1):

I was also using Text Edit in a similar fashion..But wanted something a bit easier to use... I ended up writing a simple ToDo app in Python that runs in Terminal... This code may look a bit involved, but if you copy and paste it into a .txt file  ( making sure there are not indentation problems ) name it  something like 'todo.py' ...then do  a `chmod +x` on it .... you can run this from anywhere in your account if you remember the leading './'

i.e.:  `./todo.py`

```
from __future__ import with_statement
    import sys
    import os
    import fileinput

    os.system('clear')

    print ("##############          TO DO LIST       ############")
    print ("##############                           ############")

    def showlist():
        os.system('clear')
        print ("############  Current To Do List  ######")
        print ("########################################")

        get_list = open('todo.txt')
        entire_list = get_list.readlines()
        for i in range (len(entire_list)):
            print i, entire_list[i]
        get_list.close()
        print ("########################################")
        print ("########################################")

    def appendlist():
        print ("#######################################")
        print ("#######################################")


        addtolist = str( raw_input("Enter new item:  \n"))
        thelist = open('todo.txt', 'a')
        thelist.write(str(addtolist))
        thelist.write(str('\n'))
        thelist.close()  
        showlist()


    def deleteitem():
        showlist()

            with open("todo.txt") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                if len(lines) == 0:  
                    return  
            prompt = "Enter number to delete or '0' to abort: " 
            while True:
                    input = raw_input(prompt)
                    try:
                        input = int(input, 10)
                    except ValueError:
                        print "Invalid input."
                    else:
                        if 0 <= input <= len(lines):
                            break
                        print "Input out of range."
            if input == 0:
                      return

            lines[input] = "" 

                with open("todo.txt", "w") as f:
                    f.writelines(lines)

            showlist()

    while True:

        askme = raw_input("\nDo you want to:\n(S)ee list\n(A)ppend list\n(D)elte from list\n(Q)Quit?\n")
        print str('\n')

        if askme == "S":
            showlist()
        elif askme == "A":
            appendlist()
        elif askme == "D":
            deleteitem()

        elif askme == "Q":
            sys.exit()
        else: 
            print ("Try again?")

    print ("#######################################")
    print ("#######################################")
```

Answer (score 1):

**[TeuxDeux](http://teuxdeux.com/)** is a free web app for simple task management, and it's quite nicely designed. Of all the options I give you, it's probably the one I'd use for the given workflow.

[Anxiety](http://www.anxietyapp.com/) is a free tool that integrates well with the OS X tasks support (though, in a sense, this is 'email integration')

I use [Today](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/today/) to have an overview of my day (and it's handy it's a Menu Extra and invokable by shortkey), and you can add and remove tasks right from it. It's using the OS X calendar, so if you sync the calendar/tasks somewhere else, things created in Today will show up. But really, Anxiety and Today use the same underlying todo infrastructure, and the former is free. The makers of Today also put out [Check Off](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/checkoff/), which is a todo-only app.

Other options presented [here](http://techtites.com/2009/01/22/top-5-to-do-list-managers-for-mac-os-x/). Or try the [To Do Widget](http://todo.philipefatio.com/) if you're a Dashboard user.